# How to put a text object under the cursor into an cmdline-mode command?

Tags: key-bindings, cmdline

I'm using neovim v0.8.0 (nightly build) on Arch Linux.

When in my `plugins.lua` where I have all my nvim plugins listed, I want to be able to use `gX` to open `user/repo` in my browser as `https://github.com/user/repo`.

Since the plugins are not listed as full URLs, I can't use the normal `gx`. I know they're always wrapped in single quotes so I can put them in the clip board with `"+yi'`. However, I don't know a way to put the copied text in an cmdline-mode command after that. I've tried `"+yi':!$BROWSER https://github.com/<C-S-v>` (`$BROWSER` is the browser declared in my `.profile`) but that doesn't put `:!$BROWSER https://github.com/user/repo` in the command to be executed with `<CR>`. Instead, nothing happens with I press the bound `gX` and only puts `!$BROWSER https://github.com/` (plus the next key pressed) in the command area when I press another key after `gX`.

How can I put the text object under the cursor into an cmdline-mode command?

Comment: Assuming C-S-V is your OS copy-paste? Vim can’t do that from a mapping. But you can do a regular yank and put the contents of the register (_e.g._, register a) with C-r a

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to yank your path first. You can use `<C-r><C-f>`
instead:

```
CTRL-R CTRL-F               *c_CTRL-R_CTRL-F* *c_<C-R>_<C-F>*
    CTRL-F  the Filename under the cursor
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you can put the contents with `<C-r>{register}`. Thus, the RHS of the mapping would be

```
"+yi':!$BROWSER https://github.com/<C-r>+<CR>
```